# How do I find out containing OU in results of “Find Users, Contacts, and Groups"?

Tags: active-directory, mmc

After a search, how do I get to know in which OU (Organizational Unit) a given result is?

[image: Sample screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the menu select "Edit"->"Choose Columns"->"Distinguished Name"

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: In order for me to add the Distinguished Name column to the UI, I had to enable the advanced features that @Techie007 described.

Comment: I found it under the menu at View > Choose Columns > Published At.

Answer (score 5):

- Right-click the user, and select Properties.
- Click the "Object" tab.
- The OU path is shown in the "Canonical Name of object" field.

[image: Example User Properites]

***Note:** For the Object tab to be visible, you will need to activate the Advanced Feature view via the main MMC menu:

[image: Enable Advanced View]

Comment: Thanks, but I tried on RSAT for Windows 10 and also on Windows 2012 Server R2 but neither had this Object tab. @DrNoone's solution worked for me.

Comment: No problem, which-ever works for you. :)  But yeah, I forgot that the Advanced Features view needs to be enabled for that tab to show (updated my answer).

Comment: Now I see the Object tab. Great improvement on my usability. Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

From the user properties window, you'll have tabs that says Object.

In Canonical name of object:

You'll see the complete path showing the OU of that user.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via Windows PowerShell:

Simply type:

```ps
Get-ADuser -Identity "User_Name"
```